# testing incompatible configurations with py.test

Tags: python, python-import, restart, pytest

Is there a way to have one py.test re-import classes? This is possible in Nose: each test module is imported only when it is run, so it can unload anything currently loaded, configure something at test module level, and any imports that appear after use the new configuration, and test code can use what has been imported.

This does not work in py.test because all test modules are imported at discovery time, so any import-time configuration done at module level affects all subsequently imported tests. Is there a way to tell py.test to "start afresh", i.e. unload everything? Is there a way to test py.test to restart itself (spawn a child process and parent exits)?

We could have two separate test suites (run py.test once on one folder, and run it a second time on another folder), but this is asking developers to remember to run two test suites every time they test (which can happen quite a bit if local mods affect features modified by others).

Answer (score 0):

Does running py.test with the `--boxed` option solve your problem? (You need to [install the xdist plugin](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest-xdist#installation) for this.)

There is also a detailed example of how it is used in this answer by the founder of pytest, hpk42: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11806997/54056

Comment: Thanks, sounds promising so I will try that out, then I can vote/close